# Getting build errors when generating plugin build for Opensearch 2.8.0

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

complete plugin logs scan: https://scans.gradle.com/s/xnhrbpn2syygi/failure?expanded-stacktrace=WyIwIl0#1

I am using gradle 'gradle-8.1.1-all', Java 19 (Oracle JDK), and OpenSearch 2.8.0. I am developing a plugin for this OpenSearch version. But, when I tried to generate the plugin build, I am getting the below error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'plugin-template'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools:2.8.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools:2.8.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.1.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools:2.8.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools:2.8.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
          - Variant 'testFixturesApiElements' capability org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools-test-fixtures:2.8.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
          - Variant 'testFixturesRuntimeElements' capability org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools-test-fixtures:2.8.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 1s
I tried googling some solutions and also tried some but, they didn't seem to work. My build.gradle file looks like the below one:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'opensearch.opensearchplugin'
apply plugin: 'opensearch.pluginzip'

def pluginName = 'rename'
def pluginDescription = 'Custom plugin'
def projectPath = 'org.opensearch'
def pathToPlugin = 'path.to.plugin'
def pluginClassName = 'RenamePlugin'
group = "RenameGroup"

tasks.register("preparePluginPathDirs") {
    mustRunAfter clean
    doLast {
        def newPath = pathToPlugin.replace(".", "/")
        mkdir "src/main/java/org/opensearch/$newPath"
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        pluginZip(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            pom {
              name = pluginName
              description = pluginDescription
              licenses {
                license {
                  name = "The Apache License, Version 2.0"
                  url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                }
              }
              developers {
                developer {
                  name = "OpenSearch"
                  url = "https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-plugin-template-java"
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}

opensearchplugin {
    name pluginName
    description pluginDescription
    classname "${projectPath}.${pathToPlugin}.${pluginClassName}"
    licenseFile rootProject.file('LICENSE.txt')
    noticeFile rootProject.file('NOTICE.txt')
}

// This requires an additional Jar not published as part of build-tools
loggerUsageCheck.enabled = false

// No need to validate pom, as we do not upload to maven/sonatype
validateNebulaPom.enabled = false

buildscript {
    ext {
        opensearch_version = System.getProperty("opensearch.version", "2.8.0")
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://aws.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.opensearch.gradle:build-tools:${opensearch_version}"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://aws.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}

// updateVersion: Task to auto update version to the next development iteration
task updateVersion {
    onlyIf { System.getProperty('newVersion') }
    doLast {
        ext.newVersion = System.getProperty('newVersion')
        println "Setting version to ${newVersion}."
         // String tokenization to support -SNAPSHOT
        ant.replaceregexp(file:'build.gradle', match: '"opensearch.version", "\\d.*"', replace: '"opensearch.version", "' + newVersion.tokenize('-')[0] + '-SNAPSHOT"', flags:'g', byline:true)
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error?